# Setting property values in class called from master class

Tags: c#

Thank you all in advance, this is confusing the hell out of me!

I have the two classes below to store values in before converting them to JSON, however I don't get that far as I can't load values into them.

```
    public class MergeFieldsReload
{
    public string FNAME { get; set; }
    public string LNAME { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMERID { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string CLINICCODE { get; set; }
}

public class DataReload
{
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public MergeFieldsReload merge_fields { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see MergeFieldsReload is called from DataReload, in order for JSON.Net to see it as a sub array (may have the wrong name there, feel free to correct me).

However when attempting to set the value of any field in MergeFieldsReload like so

```
DataReload data = new DataReload();

data.merge_fields.FNAME = row["FNAME"].ToString();
```

I get a 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error. I don't get this error for the two fields that are directly in DataReload, only the MergeFieldsReload.

I've no idea why this would be, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that a class is a reference value, meaning it should be constructed. You can solve this by defining a constructor.

```
public class MergeFieldsReload
{
    public string FNAME { get; set; }
    public string LNAME { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMERID { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string CLINICCODE { get; set; }
}

public class DataReload
{
    public DataReload()
    {
        merge_fields = new MergeFieldsReload();
    }

    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public MergeFieldsReload merge_fields { get; set; }
}
```

---

In C# 6.0 you can also do:

```
public class MergeFieldsReload
{
    public string FNAME { get; set; }
    public string LNAME { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMERID { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string CLINICCODE { get; set; }
}

public class DataReload
{
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public MergeFieldsReload merge_fields { get; set; } = new MergeFieldsReload();
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you very much, I'd actually got myself most of the way there (I'd realised that I needed to do something to kick start merge_fields) but didn't know how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate merge_fields before assigning its properties (second line):

```
DataReload data = new DataReload();
data.merge_fields = new MergeFieldsReload();
data.merge_fields.FNAME = row["FNAME"].ToString();
```

You could also do that in the constructor of DataReload.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the MergeFieldsReload  class in DataReload class  as

```
public class DataReload
{
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    private MergeFieldsReload _merge_fields = new  MergeFieldsReload();

    public MergeFieldsReload Merge_Fields
    {
       get { return _merge_fields ; }
       set { _merge_fields = value ;}
    }
}
```